# how to output google script with php

Tags: php

i want to output google cse by php
cse code is :

```
    <script>   (function() {
    var cx = '011900192141920744246:n9jj1rxodww';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

but it shoing white page after run !
i try add / befor ' or change ' with " but still php withe page whoing or script not working after loading page !

i try to out put like this :

```
    function search_widget()
{
$this->output(
'<aside id="search-4" class="widget widget_search">',
'<p class="widget-title">جستجو در سوالات</p>'
);
$this->output('<script>');
$this->output('(function() {');
$this->output('var cx = "011900192141920744246:n9jj1rxodww";');
$this->output('var gcse = document.createElement("script");');
$this->output('gcse.type = "text/javascript";');
$this->output('gcse.async = true;');
$this->output(' gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https:" : "http:") +');
$this->output('"//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=" + cx;');
$this->output('var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];');
$this->output('s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);');
$this->output(' }');
$this->output('});');
$this->output('</SCRIPT>');
$this->output('</aside>');
}
```

page running ok but now script not working !
please help me to output google cse script with php 
thanks

Comment: For the one that's "showing a white page" that usually means there's a server-side error.  Turn on error reporting, check the PHP logs, etc.  Examine the error to see what it is.  For the one where the client-side code isn't working, what *is* that client-side code?  If there's a client-side error, don't just look at the server-side code.  You need to examine the actual problem in order to attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
$this->output(<<<EOF
<script>   (function() {
    var cx = '011900192141920744246:n9jj1rxodww';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
EOF
);
```

If this doesn't work, check your output function.